# Long run equilibrium

Tags: economics

An industry has a total cost function : TC=$4Q^2+100Q+100$ . Where $Q$ is the quantity produced. They are asking me to find the long run equilibrium price.
How do I find it? What I've found is that i calculate the sratc(short run average total cost) and then solve for Q (while equating the derivative of sratc to 0), then find Price after substituting Q. Is this the way to go?

Comment: Depends on the model. In a model with no entry costs and perfect competition, total costs equal price long term.

Comment: yes its perfectly competitive and no entry cost. So P=TC?

Comment: @ThePoorJew I had uploaded a picture based on a wrong function. The current picture is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: In a competitive market the firms produce on the long run at a level where the average total cost function has its minimum. Thus you have to find the minimum of

$$\frac{TC(Q)}{Q}=4Q+100+\frac{100}{Q}$$

The minimum can be found by setting the derivative equal to $0$.  In this case it is good to remember that $Q$ is defined for non-negative values only. The picture below shows the course of the average cost function.

[image]

The price of the product will be equal the solution.

Comment: Okay so this means I was right at the beginning? Thanks for the answer

Comment: @ThePoorJew Maybe. The term "short run" has confused me. But you know by yourself better if you were right at the beginning. You´re welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In a perfectly competitive market, the long-run equilibrium price is the price at which the firm earns zero economic profit, which will happen at $MC=ATC$. Hence:
$$MC=TC'=(4Q^2+100Q+100)'=8Q+100\\
ATC=\frac{TC}{Q}=4Q+100+\frac{100}{Q}\\
8Q+100=4Q+100+\frac{100}{Q} \Rightarrow 4Q^2=100 \Rightarrow Q=5\\
P=MR=MC(5)=8\cdot 5+100=140.$$
Verify:
$$TR=140Q; TC=4Q^2+100Q+100\\
TR(5)-TC(5)=140\cdot 5-(4\cdot 5^2+100\cdot 5+100)=0.$$

Comment: yes, i got the same answers